# Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel "linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic" Produces Errors During Update

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, kernel

I encountered a kernel crash due to problems during an upgrade. I typed in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

It returned the following output:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic (--configure):
package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic

N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So during reboot, I went back from `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic` to `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic` and everything runs fine now.

Do I have to delete 3.13.0-68-generic because during reboot I always have to manually go to the previous kernel version? If so, how do I do it?

**NOTE:** I copied and deleted the file `20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` before going back to `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic`.

Comment: Removing the newer kernel is safe. If you are doing it manually then run `sudo update-grub` later. But if you are removing through apt-get then its not required.

Comment: Kindly run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.disable` in terminal and post the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug identified by Ubuntu: [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1514907](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1514907)

Type the following into a terminal (if you can manage to get one started):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then re-install the package or updates.

**Please note:** Kernel versions since this one have resolved the issue. Install one of the later kernels when you receive the update.

Comment: In fact, version `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic` is available. Try checking your updates again.